# More than two windows split view

Tags: macos, split-view

Is there some sort of clever hack of achieving that, because I did not find anything. I have a 27" Mac and everything is still kind of huge.

Comment: Because other people with the same question will be directed here, I think it's reasonable for answers to include paid versions, so that you and others can make the decision about whether to pay people for their work that provides you with something that you value.

Comment: @nohillside although the related question doesn't specify free/native solutions. All 5 answers on the related question are paid: Moom, BetterSnapTool, Divvy, Magnet, BetterTouchTool (and Spectacle is no longer maintained). Hence this question specifically for free/open source software (or, preferably, a native way)

Comment: I'm aware of that. But you got four answers here, two of them are for paid tools so basically not answering your question. And all of them match both questions.

Comment: @nohillside so you're closing a good question because of (2 slightly) bad answers? Wouldn't it make more sense to ping a non-answer with a downvote, and link to the related question as a comment on those answers (so the knowledge doesn't go to waste), rather than close the question?

Comment: It's linked with a rather similar one, with similar answers. Nothing gets deleted, nothing is wasted, but it makes it easier to find answers for future visitors.

Comment: I’m going to ask on meta if anyone objects to merging this with the canonical question. It’s fine being linked, but the answers fit a “what window managers exist” type question better IMO and this language will feed the canonical question with excellent use case and wording. +1 stevec it’s a great question no will bring people to our canonical answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No - you get two windows in the current implementation. One on the left and one on the right.

I suppose the notification center slide over could be considered a "third window" but you can't put an application window there - it's just a system tray of sorts.

I would look at a program like [Divvy on the Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/divvy-window-manager/id413857545?mt=12) for customizing a workspace with multiple tiled windows. It's not split view, but it's far more flexible and able to make use of the 27 inch display space to quite a granular basis.

Answer (score 21):

## Rectangle

You can use [Rectangle](https://rectangleapp.com/) to achieve this for free.

> Rectangle is a window management app based on Spectacle, written in Swift.

After downloading, installing, and granting the app accessibility permissions in System Preferences, you'll be able to enable the default keyboard shortcut scheme, which allows you to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>opt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>/<kbd>I</kbd>/<kbd>K</kbd>/<kbd>J</kbd> to snap a window to the top left/top right/bottom right/bottom left, respectively. By assigning four windows each to one of these four positions, you can create a four-way split screen view (and if you enable Dock and Menu Bar hiding, you might be able to get a bit more screen real estate, if needed).

Comment: This one worked quite well. I split the screen into 3 with minimal shortcuts. Amazing for a free app!

Comment: Tried this as well. It's super helpful.

Comment: Such a good recommendation, does what it says, great default shortcuts, and it's free.

Answer (score 8):

I can recommend:

- [Spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com/) which is free, you can move and expand windows to
  sides and corners with keyboard shortcuts
- [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net/) which is paid-for, and includes drag-to-edge to size windows to sides or corners, among many other features

Comment: Should be marked as best answer!!

Comment: I found a similar tool with a similar name, let me add as a comment for reference by future visitors, BetterSnapTool at https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12

Comment: BetterSnapTool is now paid for, but cheaper than BetterTouchTool. They're by the same developer, and BetterTouchTool includes the snapping functionality, but also a lot more with respect to defining custom keyboard shortcuts, mouse gestures, and more.

Answer (score 6):

## yabai

If you want a more powerful alternative to Rectangle, you could use the free and open-soure [Yabai](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai), which you can configure however you like.

> yabai is a window management utility that is designed to work as an extension to the built-in window manager of macOS. yabai allows you to control your windows, spaces and displays freely using an intuitive command line interface and optionally set user-defined keyboard shortcuts using [skhd](https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd) and other third-party software.

Comment: It's worth noting that Yabai requires that "System Integrity Protection…be (partially) disabled" in order for "many advanced features" to function.

Comment: The basic tiling functions do not require SIP to be disabled

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully something like this becomes a standard Mac feature.  I like the split screen feature, but sometimes I want/need more than two screens.  I found a pretty good solution on the Apps store that will let you have split screen, one window half/two in quarters, or 4 windows is quarters.   It is called Magnet.  Works great on OSx Sierra, and is much cheaper than Divvy.  Here's the [link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/magnet/id441258766?mt=12)!

Answer (score 4):

The app I am now using is [Magnet](https://magnet.crowdcafe.com/). It is available on the [Mac AppStore](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/magnet/id441258766?mt=12) and performs beautifully. It has shortcuts, graphical buttons and you can drag the windows to the sides of the screen to snap them to halves or to corners to snap them to quarters.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## BetterSnapTool

An app you might want to check is [BetterSnapTool](https://www.macbed.com/bettersnaptool/). It does what you want and is available from the Mac App Store. It sells for $2.99. I know you wanted a free app but I couldn't find one for the Mac.

> BetterSnapTool allows you to easily manage your window positions and sizes by either dragging them to one of your screens corners or to the top, left or right side of your screen. This lets you easily maximize your windows or position them side by side. In addition, you can set keyboard shortcuts in order to move and resize your windows the way you want.

Answer (score 3):

### SizeUp

[SizeUp](https://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) is a window manager app like the others. It costs $12.99 at the time of writing, but offers **unlimited free** trial (it just reminds you every now and then to pay).

> SizeUp allows you to quickly resize and position your windows with keyboard shortcuts or a handy menu bar icon.

It is **not** open source, though.

Answer (score 2):

@Harry is actually providing a very good recommendation without being very specific about it.

[Spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com/) does (almost) exactly what you're looking for. It's not strictly speaking split view, but it allows you to split windows between the three third of the screen via simple shortcuts:

[image]

In addition, it's free and open-source.

Comment: Love the open source part of it more than free part :)
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Me from the future here; I ended up settling for [Magnet](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/magnet/id441258766?l=en&mt=12)

It has nice logical shortcuts to snap windows to quarters, halves and thirds of the screen and supports dragging to the edges of the screen, like in Windows. Easily worth the 1.09€ for me.

[image: screenshot]

---

Update 2019/2020:

Ended up switching to [Divvy](https://mizage.com/divvy/). It allows me to place windows anywhere on a customizable grid (kind of like a less aggressive tiling window manager). And I can define custom shortcuts. So I took Magnet’s shortcuts and added a whole bunch of other ones, like centering, top left sixth, bottom quarter, etc.

It also allows to set a custom window separation, which I think looks pretty good.

[image: divvy]
[image: grid]

Answer (score 1):

## Moom

This is my favorite... I have tried quite a few, and paid for them.

### there is a quick menu on the window

[image]

### you can split into blocks which are configurable

[image]

### and can be triggered when switching displays

[image]

### this is the help screen ....

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/360657/edit) the post to include a link to the app homepage/App Store link?

Comment: Here is a link: https://apps.apple.com/app/moom/id419330170

Answer (score 0):

[BetterSnapTool](https://apps.apple.com/sg/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12) has worked well for me for years

Answer (score 0):

Its not the same feautre as Windows, But little bit default Mac feature

Follow the steps

1. Four finger down. You will window desktop bar
2. Drag the application to besides desktop.(Make sure you are not dragging into desktop but creating new app pane besides, the mistake i was doing)
3. You can now drag one more application to the lonely single applcation in desktop bar.
4. Now they will split evenly in two
   [image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome the SE.network and thanks for contributing. Unfortunately, your answer misses the mark. The question was about how to get more than two windows side by side.