# Open source 4-way split screen on macOS?

Tags: software-recommendation, productivity, split-view

macOS's [split view](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204948) allows a screen to be divided into two, with an application in each part.

Is there any open source / free way to do a ***4-way*** split screen (e.g. a screen split into quarters)?

[image]

I found two *paid* programs [divvy](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/divvy-window-manager/id413857545?mt=12) and [magnet](https://magnet.crowdcafe.com/) (both discussed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/228192/290197)), and also had a [look around GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=4+split+mac), but I couldn't spot any native way or free software that can achieve a 4-way split screen on macOS. Is there any native/free way to do this?

Comment: @benwiggy We already have a question about this (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228192/more-than-two-windows-split-view?noredirect=1&lq=1), with lots of answers